# Spotify App Remote SDK: CouldNotFindSpotifyApp error

Tags: java, android-studio, spotify

I'm trying to build an app which integrates the Spotify App Remote SDK. However, when I try to connect to Spotify using the SDK, the CouldNotFindSpotifyApp error is thrown even though the Spotify app is installed on the device.

I found other solutions on stackoverflow that asked me to add a queries in the manifest
`

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.spotify.music" />
</queries>
```

`
But that doesn't work and gives me the same error

I tried to connect to the spotify api using this code:
`

```
ConnectionParams connectionParams =
        new ConnectionParams.Builder(CLIENT_ID)
                .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
                .showAuthView(true)
                .build();
SpotifyAppRemote.connect(this, connectionParams,
        new Connector.ConnectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onConnected(SpotifyAppRemote spotifyAppRemote) {
                mSpotifyAppRemote = spotifyAppRemote;
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Connected! Yay!");

                // Now you can start interacting with App Remote
                connected();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
                if (error instanceof NotLoggedInException || error instanceof UserNotAuthorizedException) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Other Error");
                } else if (error instanceof CouldNotFindSpotifyApp) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "User Not Found");
                }
            }
        });
```

`

And instead of connecting it gave me an error

```
CouldNotFindSpotifyApp
```